# Covariance matrices should be equal but are not

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, covariance

I'm computing covariance in two ways that I think should tie out, but they do not.
Method 1: Compute the covariance matrix of a slice of an array of data
Method 2: Compute the covariance matrix of the full array of data, and reference an equivalent slice of that matrix.
The differences are tiny (order 1e-18), but these differences are growing with subsequent calculations in my code and preventing reproducibility.  Is this a floating point issue?  If so I'd still like to understand why it's happening and how to avoid it.
I'm on numpy 1.16.3
Thanks!

```py
import numpy as np

state = np.random.RandomState(1)
X = state.rand(40,100)
A = np.cov(X[:20])
B = np.cov(X)[:20,:20]
print(np.array_equal(A, B))
diff = A - B
print(np.max(diff))
```

I would have expected a True result from array_equal, but I get False

Comment: by running you example i get True response and difference equal to 0. Numpy v.1.16.3

Comment: I can reproduce, but I'm in 1.12.1

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi That's odd, thanks for checking

Comment: @DanielF Thanks for checking, seems like the issue is lower level than Numpy

Comment: You can not rely on such reproducibility. Maybe the operation x * y transpose are performed with optimized blas dger or something like that, and results will then depend on usage of fma, block size of submatrix operations etc... different paths, different results.